# why my puppy pee and poo inside only when he is home with my partner

Tags: dogs, behavior

my puppy 14 weeks house trained never have a accident when I am home. but when I leave to work few days for week he is alone with my husband and he pee and poo inside the house.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My dog is destroying things and peeing inside when I am at work. How can I get him to stop?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/my-dog-is-destroying-things-and-peeing-inside-when-i-am-at-work-how-can-i-get-h)

Comment: @AllisonC 14 weeks vs. 7.5 years? I don’t think that’s a duplicate at all?

Comment: @Jay, welcome! Can you define “house trained” for us, please? At 14 weeks that can mean different things from you keeping an eye on him and encouraging regular potty breaks to your pup actively indicating he needs to go.

Comment: @Stephie there's a ton of questions similar to this one, that's just the one I selected. Regardless, there's also very little information here and I suspect it may not be a puppy issue, but a husband issue.

Comment: @AllisonC same suspicion here ;-)